# issue with slf4j on thymeleaf

Tags: slf4j, thymeleaf

Trying to use thymeleaf 2.1.3.RELEASE and 3.0.0.BETA01 on web server that has to use slf4j 1.5.10 and I get error

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.6.99 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10
```

Any way we can force thymeleaf to use slf4j 1.5.10 ?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing slf4j-api-1.5.x.jar with a later version, say slf4j-api-1.7.x.jar should do the trick. Assuming you are using Maven, can you post the output of `mvn dependency:tree` command for your project ?

Comment: as indicated, it has to use whatever version it is already there.